# THREE.SpriteCanvasMaterial not working

Tags: javascript, three.js, html5-canvas, textures

This code (based on [this](http://threejs.org/examples/#canvas_particles_shapes) [code](http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_particles_billboards.html)):

```
    drawCircle = (context) ->
        pos = 0.5
        radius = 0.5
        context.scale(0.05, -0.05)
        context.beginPath()
        context.arc(pos, pos, radius, 0, 2*Math.PI, false)
        context.fillStyle = 'white'
        context.fill()

    m = new THREE.SpriteCanvasMaterial( {program: drawCircle } )
    s = new THREE.Sprite( m )
```

returns an error

```
    Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined.
```

In Three.js: line 36534:

```
    _gl.uniform2f( uniforms.uvScale, material.uvScale.x, material.uvScale.y );
```

It seems that the material uvScale and uvOffset properties are not properly initialized... Why ?
If I set those properties myself:

```
    m.uvScale = new THREE.Vector2()
    m.uvOffset = new THREE.Vector2()
```

Errors disappear but I can't see the particles (I don't know where to draw in the canvas, and why should I scale it).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using a material which is meant for canvas2D in the webglrenderer. You should either use the canvasrenderer or use a different material (SpriteMaterial).